# Индекс в forEach()

Tags: javascript, foreach

```
Array.from(items).forEach((item,index)=>{
    item.style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[index]})`
)}
```

когда индекс будет равен 6, нужно обнулить его до 1 и чтобы он продолжил увеличивать себя до 6 и снова уменьшил себя до 1

<--
если использовать такую конструкцию он уменьшает себя до 1, но не продолжает расти -->

```
index == 6 ? index = 1 : index
```

Comment: остаток от деления на 6 возьмите и используйте

Comment: forEach не работает как while, и индекс поменять у вас не получится, он на это и внимание не обратит, просто перебирает массив. Делайте собственный цикл

Comment: Использование остатка от деления на 6 помогло))